# Edit table row from bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

In this project, I need to make edit table function. 
When edit button is clicked a modal will appear.
The modal will contain a form that has to be filled with current table data from the selected row, and current data will be overwritten when save button is clicked.
Each new row will have their row ID and an edit button when added to the table.

Here is the snippet:

```js
function add_row() {
  var code = document.getElementById('code').value;
  if (code == "") {
    alert("code empty!");
    return false;
  } else if (isNaN(code)) {
    alert("code must be numbers");
    return false;
  }

  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  if (name == "") {
    alert("name empty!");
    return false;
  } else if (!(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(name.replace(/\s/g, '')))) {
    alert("name must be letters");
    return false;
  }

  var year = document.getElementById('year').value;
  if (year == "") {
    alert("year empty!");
    return false;
  } else if (isNaN(year)) {
    alert("year must number");
    return false;
  }

  var major = document.getElementById('major').value;
  if (major == "") {
    alert("major empty!");
    return false;
  }

  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  if (address == "") {
    alert("address empty!");
    return false;
  }

  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var et = email.indexOf("@");
  var dot = email.indexOf(".");
  if (email == "") {
    alert("email empty!");
    return false;
  } else if (et < 1 || dot < et + 2 || dot + 2 > email.length) {
    alert('email must has @ and domain');
    return false;
    console.log('failures');
  }

  var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
  if (phone == "") {
    alert("phone empty!");
    return false;
  } else if (isNaN(phone)) {
    alert("phone must number");
    return false;
  }

  var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
  //var newRow = table.insertRow(table.rows.length / 2 + 1);

  var table = document.getElementById("data_table");
  var table_len = (table.rows.length/ 2+1) - 1;
  var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML = "<tr id='row" + table_len + "'><td id='code_row" + table_len + "'>" + code + "</td><td id='name_row" + table_len + "'>" + name + "</td><td id='year_row" + table_len + "'>" + year + "</td><td id='major_row" + table_len + "'>" + major + "</td><td id='address_row" + table_len + "'>" + address + "</td><td id='email_row" + table_len + "'>" + email + "</td><td id='phone_row" + table_len + "'>" + phone + "</td> <td><input type='button' id='edit_button" + table_len + "' value='Edit' onclick='edit_row(" + table_len + ")' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal2'> <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row(" + table_len + ")'></td></tr>";

}

function edit_row(no) {
  var code = document.getElementById("code_row" + no);
  var name = document.getElementById("name_row" + no);
  var year = document.getElementById("year_row" + no);
  var major = document.getElementById("major_row" + no);
  var address = document.getElementById("address_row" + no);
  var email = document.getElementById("email_row" + no);
  var phone = document.getElementById("phone_row" + no);

  code.value = document.getElementById("code_row" + no);
  name.value = document.getElementById("code_row" + no);
  year.value = document.getElementById("code_row" + no);
  major.value = document.getElementById("code_row" + no);
  address.value = document.getElementById("code_row" + no);
  email.value = document.getElementById("code_row" + no);
  phone.value = document.getElementById("code_row" + no);

  var code_data = name.innerHTML;
  var name_data = name.innerHTML;
  var year_data = year.innerHTML;
  var major_data = major.innerHTML;
  var address_data = address.innerHTML;
  var email_data = email.innerHTML;
  var phone_data = phone.innerHTML;

}

function save_row(no) {
  var code = document.getElementById('code').value;
  if (code == "") {
    alert("code empty!");
    return false;
  } else if (isNaN(code)) {
    alert("code must number");
    return false;
  }

  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  if (name == "") {
    alert("name empty!");
    return false;
  } else if (!(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(name.replace(/\s/g, '')))) {
    alert("name must letters");
    return false;
  }

  var year = document.getElementById('year').value;
  if (year == "") {
    alert("year empty!");
    return false;
  } else if (isNaN(year)) {
    alert("year must number");
    return false;
  }

  var major = document.getElementById('major').value;
  if (major == "") {
    alert("major empty!");
    return false;
  }

  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  if (address == "") {
    alert("address empty!");
    return false;
  }

  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var et = email.indexOf("@");
  var dot = email.indexOf(".");
  if (email == "") {
    alert("email empty!");
    return false;
  } else if (et < 1 || dot < et + 2 || dot + 2 > email.length) {
    alert('email must contains @ and domain');
    return false;

  }

  var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
  if (phone == "") {
    alert("phone empty!");
    return false;
  } else if (isNaN(phone)) {
    alert("phone must number");
    return false;
  }

  var code_val = document.getElementById("code_row" + no).value;
  var name_val = document.getElementById("name_row" + no).value;
  var year_val = document.getElementById("year_row" + no).value;
  var major_val = document.getElementById("major_row" + no).value;
  var address_val = document.getElementById("address_row" + no).value;
  var email_val = document.getElementById("email_row" + no).value;
  var phone_val = document.getElementById("phone_row" + no).value;

  document.getElementById("code_row" + no).innerHTML = code_val;
  document.getElementById("name_row" + no).innerHTML = name_val;
  document.getElementById("year_row" + no).innerHTML = year_val;
  document.getElementById("major_row" + no).innerHTML = major_val;
  document.getElementById("address_row" + no).innerHTML = address_val;
  document.getElementById("email_row" + no).innerHTML = email_val;
  document.getElementById("phone_row" + no).innerHTML = phone_val;
}

function reset_form() 
{
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">

    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Data</h4>
      </div>

      <!--Body pop up-->
      <div class="modal-body">

        <form id="myForm">
          Code :
          <br>
          <input type="text" placeholder="code" name="code" id="code">

          <br>name :
          <br>
          <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name" id="name">

          <br>year :
          <br>
          <input type="text" placeholder="year" name="year" id="year">

          <br>major :
          <br>
          <!--<input type="text" placeholder="major" name="major" id="major">-->
          <form action="/action_page.php" name="major" id="major">
            <select name="major" id="major">
                    <option value="Akuntansi">Akuntansi</option>
                    <option value="Teknik Infomatika">Teknik Informatika</option>
                    <option value="Psikologi">Psikologi</option>
                    <option value="Hukum">Hukum</option>
                    <option value="Politik">Politik</option>
                  </select>
          </form>

          address :
          <br>
          <!--<input type="text" placeholder="address" name="address" id="address">-->
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" placeholder="address" name="address" id="address"></textarea>

          <br>Email :
          <br>
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email">

          <br>phone :
          <br>
          <input type="text" placeholder="phone" name="phone" id="phone">
        </form>

      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">

        <button type="button" onClick="reset_form()" id="btnCancel" style="background-color:#800003" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
        <button type="button" onClick="save_row()" id="btnSave" style="background-color:#003300" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question ? Have you isolated a problem and can't solve it ?

Comment: I wanted to fill the edit form with current table data when edit button is clicked and overwrite it when save button clicked, so i think the question is how the edit_row and save_row function will be? Thank you in advance

Comment: So, you are asking for someone to make this feature for you?

Comment: You can start by correcting your html: `name:` attributes are invalid, you shoud use `name=` as any other attribute.

Comment: I guess so, if it is appropriate to ask. I am not really good with Javascript.

Comment: It's is done Mr. @Niloct

Comment: No need for Mr. :) You could add this in a snippet actually, you just pasted 4 snippets at the beginning instead of a single one. Let me show you.

Comment: Oh im sorry. I think that would make things clearer if i post that separately because my codes are very messy.

Comment: The javascript must be in a single snippet to work together.

Comment: You can see the snippet working now. There is no `reset_form` function defined on the snippet, you can edit the snippet and add it. You can see that the right button now shows some alerts for empty fields.

Comment: added reset_form function

Comment: Try onclick funtion and use closest("tr") jQuery function to get the data.

Comment: You have nested forms. your reset function doesn't work for the fields below major select.

Comment: Actually I copied the whole 'add' from to the edit from, maybe i should remove it for now so we can focus on what i asked?

Comment: So why are you calling `insertRow` in 2 tables (the `[0]`th table and `#data_table` )? They aren't defined in the snippet html.

Comment: Well I'll let someone pick up from here, or myself in about 8h.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, sometimes i learned things from different websites. I think i fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

It's more important to make clean code now than bothering with validation, you must be very realistic with your validation rules or it can backfire you very easily.

Some further advices on your code:

- You still are missing the `<TABLE>` element on your question html snippet
- You still have two table DOM references in javascript, the first table on the document (i.e. `document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0]`), and table with id `data_table`. You're inserting rows in only the later.
- `insertRow()` DOESN'T need a parameter to append the new row to the end of the table, it's the default behavior (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow)).

---

Also, you could refactor the validation code to an function, say `validate_error_message()`. It should return the error message of validation, or a blank string. The beginning of it would be, for instance, porting:

```
var code = document.getElementById('code').value;
if (code == "") {
  alert("code empty!");
  return false;
} else if (isNaN(code)) {
  alert("code must be numbers");
  return false;
}
```

to

```
function validate_error_message() {
    var code = document.getElementById('code').value;
    if (code == "") {
      return "code empty!";
    } else if (isNaN(code)) {
      return "code must be numbers";
    }
    /* ... more validations */
    return "";
}
```

Now, on `add_row()` and `save_row()`, delete all the validations, and wrap the code inside i.e. `add_row()` with :

```
function add_row() {
     var err_msg = validate_error_message();
     if (err_msg == "") {
         /* add_row() body */
     }
     else {
         alert(err_msg);
     } 
}
```